# CMS Shopping Cart with Deal Timer

Tags: php, mysql

I need recommendation for open source shopping cart that can sell item with timer for the deal like

1. http://www.mydeal.com.my/
2. http://www.mydeal.com.au/

with software criteria:

1. PHP >= v5.2
2. Database MySQL

Answer (score 0):

You can use JOOMLA and VirtueMart - ***Virtuemart Sale countdown timer***

[Here](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension-specific/virtuemart-extensions/virtuemart-coupons/16956)

[Demo](http://addonstreet.com/demo/virtuemart-sale-countdown-timer/)

*EDIT:* So, [Open Cart](http://www.opencart.com/) is an Alternative. There is [many Countdowns](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension&filter_search=Countdown), but all with a commercial licence, I think.

Comment: Thank you, but i prefer CMS is built specially for Shopping cart not general website like joomla.

Comment: @GusDeCooL, maybe open cart?

Comment: As i know, open cart didn't have built in feature for that. Can you inform me maybe there is some extiontion for opencart that can do that?

Comment: Thank you, will soon test it.